# After writing a dict to CSV , how do you revert this to retrieve the original dict

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a python script which saves my dict into a csv

My dict has the following structure:

```
 dict_data= dict()
 
 xplanes=[7,3,10,11]
 field = ['T','V','U']
 for ppl in xplanes:
     dict_data[ppl] = dict()
     for ff in field
           dict_data[ppl][ff] = ...Some... numpy array
```

Now I write the dict to a csv file

```
  with open('file.csv','w') as f:
      write=csv.write(f)
      for k,v in dict_data.items():
           write.writerow([k,v])
```

The csv file has the following structure:

```
   7,"{'T': array([ 637525.25 ...... , ], dtype=float32)
    ,  'V': array([ 637525.25 ...... , ], dtype=float32)
    ,  'U': array([ 637525.25 ...... , ], dtype=float32)}"
   3,"{'T': array([ 637525.25 ...... , ], dtype=float32) ....
      "}
```

Now I am struggling to read that file and revert it back to the dict I used to have, namely, `dict_data`

Comment: Any specific reason you are using csv? Using json would be much easier, with dumps/loads.

Comment: Too late now since I already got them stored .

Comment: it almost looks like you could `eval` it?

Comment: are your arrays separated by spaces or commas?

Comment: separated by commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it did not go as smooth as i thought, so it's a bit ugly but should do

```
from numpy import array, float32
import re

txt="""
7,"{'T': array([1,2,3], dtype=float32)
,  'V': array([1,2,3], dtype=float32)
,  'U': array([1,2,3], dtype=float32)}"
3,"{'T': array([1,2,3], dtype=float32)
,  'V': array([1,2,3], dtype=float32)
,  'U': array([1,2,3], dtype=float32)}"
10,"{'T': array([1,2,3], dtype=float32)
,  'V': array([1,2,3], dtype=float32)
,  'U': array([1,2,3], dtype=float32)}"
11,"{'T': array([1,2,3], dtype=float32)
,  'V': array([1,2,3], dtype=float32)
,  'U': array([1,2,3], dtype=float32)}"
"""

splitter=re.compile('(^\d{1,2}),', re.MULTILINE)
get_k_v=re.compile("'([TUV])': (array[^)]+\))")
splits=re.split(splitter, txt)
old_dict={}
for split in splits:
    if split=='\n':
        continue
    elif split.isdigit():
        k=int(split)
    else:
        res=re.findall(get_k_v, split)
        old_dict[k]={k: eval(v) for k,v in res}

print(old_dict[7]['T'])
>>> [1. 2. 3.]
```

Comment: could you explain how this will be used if instead of having TUV you would have some with multiple characters, e.g. T_MEAN, T_MSQR?

Comment: instead of `([TUV])` `(T_MEAN|T_MSQR)` should do

Answer (score 0):

Read the csv file with read_csv from pandas.
Then use to_dict() method.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
print(data.to_dict())
```

Comment: this won't take into account the dict for each dict[ppl]